# why does p never go over 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im playing with recursion, and ended up with this :

```
n = 0

def func(f) :
    print("setting p to 1")  #NEW#
    p = 1 #local var
    global n
    n+=1
    print(n)
    if n > 5 :
        print("returning")
        return
    print("calling f(f) with id() of " + str(id(f)))
    f(f)
    print("incrementing p") #NEW#
    p +=1
    print("p = " + str(p))

print(str(id(func)))
func(func)
```

Ok my question is, if f is always the same id (which it is), and therefore always the same object (I bet thats where Im wrong somehow), shouldnt p be the same p and therefore be incremented past 2? Instead its treating each p as if it were local to a different object.

output :

```
178374636
1
calling f(f) with id() of 178374636
2
calling f(f) with id() of 178374636
3
calling f(f) with id() of 178374636
4
calling f(f) with id() of 178374636
5
calling f(f) with id() of 178374636
6
returning
p = 2
p = 2
p = 2
p = 2
p = 2
```

NEW OUTPUT WITH NEW COMMENTARY

```
178374572
setting p to 1
1
calling f(f) with id() of 178374572
setting p to 1
2
calling f(f) with id() of 178374572
setting p to 1
3
calling f(f) with id() of 178374572
setting p to 1
4
calling f(f) with id() of 178374572
setting p to 1
5
calling f(f) with id() of 178374572
setting p to 1
6
returning
incrementing p
p = 2
incrementing p
p = 2
incrementing p
p = 2
incrementing p
p = 2
incrementing p
p = 2
```

Comment: because on line one of your function you do `p = 1`...

Comment: @het : I also have a line n+=1 and a line p+=1 yet p never reaches above 2 while n gets to 6. Its deeper than that.

Comment: It is what Loan says. `p` is a local variable, `n` in contrast is a global variable. Everytime the function runs p will be "reset", `n`, being global is not reset.

Comment: @jason No it isn't. `n` starts at 0, and each time `func` is called it executes `n += 1`. But each time `func` is called it executes `p = 1` and then `p += 1`. So even if `p` did keep its value between calls (which it doesn't), your code **explicitly asks** for `p` to be reset on each call and always have the same value at the end.

Comment: Maybe Im lost what happens after return. Give me a minute to stare at this more.

Comment: ok I added some lines to show when p gets modified. It gets set to 1 before any incrementing is applied to it. After return, its incremented 5 times. Ill modify my original post and output to show this. Im not saying youre wrong so dont give up on me yet!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this function recursive, since it calls its argument, rather than itself. If you pass it itself as its argument, it becomes recursive, but that's neither her nor there. Call `func(print)` and it will not recurse!

Comment: @Blckknight yeah youre technically correct, the best kind of correct. Ive learned so much from this example its silly. Thank you for your input! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

p is a local variable and that has nothing to do with the fact that func always has the same id. each call to the func will create a new stack frame with new instances of local variables

Comment: so, stupid followup, how do the functions get kept track of? I thought if something had the same id as something else, then it essentially WAS the other thing. There must be some internal record keeping Im not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a misconception about how functions and local variables work. You are correct that `f` is always the same object, but that doesn't imply that `p` keeps its value when you keep calling `f`. A local variable is local to one particular execution of a function, not to the function itself.

Take a simple function like this:

```
def plus1(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y
```

`plus1` doesn't "contain" a value for `x` or `y`. If it did, what value would it have before I called the function? Instead the data defining `plus1` is a set of instructions for what to do when it is given a value for `x`. It only contains `x` as a way of referring to the argument value (which it hasn't been given yet), and `y` as a way of referring to a value it will create during execution.

When you actually call `plus1(5)`, then the code of `plus1` is executed with `x` bound to `5`. But that binding is only relevant inside that particular call of the function, and once the call is done the value is thrown away. At any given time there could be 0, 1, or any other number of calls to a function currently being executed, and each will have its own local variable bindings.

Since your function calls itself (indirectly), this does in fact happen in your program. Before you call `func` there are 0 "versions" of `p` in existence. Then there are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and finally 6 versions (the 6th one is never printed, because `func` returns when `n > 5`). This then drops back to 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 versions.

That's how local variables work, and why Python complains that you have to assign a local variable before you can read it. Outside of a particular call it's meaningless to ask for the value of `p`, because there could be zero or many values which might be called `p`. That means calling `func` also can't start from `p` as already acted on by other calls, because which `p` should it start from?

Comment: > At any given time there could be 0, 1, or any other number of calls to a function currently being executed, and each will have its own local variable bindings. THAT IS NEW TO ME! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some confusion about recursion. A recursive function is one that calls itself. Your example function instead calls its argument `f`, which means it is only recursive if it gets passed itself as `f`.

Here's what a really recursive function looks like:

```
def recursive(arg):
    if arg <= 0:
        return "base case"
    else:
        return "recursive({}) returned <{}>".format(arg-1, recursive(arg-1))
```

Example output:

```
>>> recursive(0)
'base case'
>>> recursive(3)
'recursive(2) returned <recursive(1) returned <recursive(0) returned <base case>>>'
```

As you can see in that example, you always need to have a base case where the function doesn't recurse, or you'll never get to the end.

Information can be passed "up" the chain of recursive calls by modifying the arguments that are being passed in each call. Information can be passed "down" the chain by modifying the return value of the recursive call in order to create your own return value.

In general, function calls never modify local variables within the calling function (there are a few ways they can, but they're not common). For a recursive call, that means that each call of the function has it's own version of each of the local variables. Function parameters are local variables, so they're also unique to each call (and can be modified independently of each other).

```
def recursive_vars(arg):
    loc = 10 # a local variable

    print("initial values of local variables are: arg = {}, loc = {}".format(arg, loc))

    if arg == 0:
        print("arg is zero, so this is the base case. Returning without recusing!")
        return

    print("decrementing arg and loc by one each")
    arg -= 1
    loc -= 1

    print("before recursion, local variables are: arg = {}, loc = {}".format(arg, loc))

    print("recursing")
    recursive_vars(arg)

    print("after recursion, local variables are: arg = {}, loc = {}".format(arg, loc))

    print("done")
```

Output:

```
>>> recursive_vars(0)
initial values of local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 10
arg is zero, so this is the base case. Returning without recusing!
>>> recursive_vars(3)
initial values of local variables are: arg = 3, loc = 10
decrementing arg and loc by one each
before recursion, local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 9
recursing
initial values of local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 10
decrementing arg and loc by one each
before recursion, local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 9
recursing
initial values of local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 10
decrementing arg and loc by one each
before recursion, local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 9
recursing
initial values of local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 10
arg is zero, so this is the base case. Returning without recusing!
after recursion, local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 9
done
after recursion, local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 9
done
after recursion, local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 9
done
```

Here's what that last part of that output would look like if it was indented based on how deep in the recursion it was:

```
initial values of local variables are: arg = 3, loc = 10
decrementing arg and loc by one each
before recursion, local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 9
recursing
  initial values of local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 10
  decrementing arg and loc by one each
  before recursion, local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 9
  recursing
    initial values of local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 10
    decrementing arg and loc by one each
    before recursion, local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 9
    recursing
      initial values of local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 10
      arg is zero, so this is the base case. Returning without recusing!
    after recursion, local variables are: arg = 0, loc = 9
    done
  after recursion, local variables are: arg = 1, loc = 9
  done
after recursion, local variables are: arg = 2, loc = 9
done
```

As you can see, in every case the local variables in each layer have the same values on both sides of the recursive calls. Because the `arg` variable gets passed as a parameter, it looks like is shared between the calls, but that's an illusion. As you can see when the function calls unwind, the outer calls didn't have their `arg` variable's value modified by the inner calls. (Things are a bit more complicated if you pass mutable objects, like `list` instances as arguments, but that's not important for a basic understanding of recursion.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do sth like to change p. E.g., to use `p` as a global variable in the function.

```
p = 0

def my_func(...):
   ...
   p +=1 
   ...
   return p

p = my_func(...)
p = my_func(...)
...
```